# Can Subversion merge 2 projects without branching first?

Tags: svn, visual-sourcesafe-2005

I am in the process of migrating several projects from SourceSafe to Subversion. However, one project is in the middle of development. That project is not currently branched in SourceSafe, however the last release was labeled (tagged) in SourceSafe so I can get a copy of it.

If I get a working copy of that SourceSafe label (tag) and commit it to Subversion as the "trunk", then commit my current working copy with the latest changes to a subdirectory below the "branches" directory for the same project, is it then possible to merge my projects together when I have completed the development in the branch? Or does Subversion only allow merging if a branch was done first?

I am open for suggestions on how to best migrate this project (both trunk and branch) into Subversion if the above question is totally out of line. I am a newbie with Subversion, and have only tried branching in SourceSafe.

Answer (score 0):

why not copy over working version to both trunk and your own branch. Then you can start working on your own branch and check back in your changes.

I am new to SBN as well. (used Perforce in the past). but SVN doesnt seem to have check out history, so you can check out as many time as you want from number of locations.  In perforce, it doesnt allow you that ( you had to create workspace for it).

So in your case, you can check in/commit in both locations (trunk and branches) and then commit your changes to your own branch

Comment: The problem is I have several months of work that is in progress and don't currently have a stable build. I need to go back a version for a stable build and then I will have 2 working copies (old version and new version) to import into Subversion. What I am wondering is will Subversion allow me to merge them if they are completely separate projects vs a branch that was derived from the trunk within Subversion?

Comment: I havent tried that, best way would be to give it a quick try. try to create dummy solution in trunk and create similar structure in branches and see if you can merge